# Como pegar o href de um elemento e atribuí-lo também como id do mesmo sem o sharp (#)?

Tags: jquery

Estou usando um *shortcode* em Wordpress que só me dá a possibilidade de inserir os atributos seguintes:

```
<a href="#anatomia" target="_self" class="dt-sc-button small">Inscreva</a>
<a href="#anatomia" target="_self" class="dt-sc-button small">Saiba mais</a>
```

Gostaria de então pegar o atributo `href` e inseri-lo como ID do elemento. Visto que pode ter mais de um elemento (7 pra começar), pensei em colocar dentro d'um `foreach` pra repetir isso pra todos os elementos.

Outra coisa ... pensei em usar a classe `dt-sc-button` para restringir a aplicação a estes elementos.

Comment: $('.dt-sc-button').each(function(){ this.id = $(this).attr('href').slice(1); }); <- acho que isso dá conta do recado

Comment: Para que necessitas inserir IDs nestes elementos?

Comment: Para fazer chamadas diferentes para cada curso. Preço diferente, data e local diferentes etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tens uma classe para esses elementos podes usar `$('.dt-sc-button')` e depois iterá-los com um `.each()`.

Para ir buscar o href podes usar `$(this).attr('href')` dentro desse `.each()` e depois só precisas tirar o primeiro caractere. O `.slice(1)` faz isso.

Sugestão de código:

```
$('.dt-sc-button').each(function () {
    this.id = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
});
```

Comment: Tem dois **href** envoltos para cada classe. Como não atribuir o id ao segundo botão?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius podes mostrar como é o HTML nesse caso?

Comment: Na verdade, é só atribuir um outro **href** para o segundo botão. Obrigado.